# unity2d - sceneview and gameview show different size (and different position) of button

Tags: unity-game-engine

The size and position of my button-gameobjects are different in the sceneview and the gameview. In the sceneview, compared to the rest of the game, the buttons show about 60 times larger than in gameview. Here is an example how it looks like when i make a new button:

(compare the size to that other object to the right of the button)
[example button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKLCL.png)

I use unity version 2018.4.24f1. I use Visual Studio 2019 version 4.8.03752. I made that example button before gamestart. I made a new camera which showed the same result.

Comment: This is normal.  The button is drawn on a UI Canvas.  The dimensions of the canvas such as 1920 x 1080 would equate to 1920 unity units by 1080 unity units which is pretty huge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to make everything else bigger so i dont have that problem?